# Bluetooth: Do i need to know the UUID of the Devices?

Tags: android

I want to connect my Nexus 7 device with my Nexus 4 device and later i want to connect my Nexus 7 device with a micro controller. **Do i have to know the UUID** of my devices to connect them using bluetooth?

Are the UUID's being exchanged when i pair my devices?

If yes: Why is there a defined UUID in android example?

```
public class BluetoothService extends Thread {
    private static final String TAG = BluetoothService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;  
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
    private Handler handler = null;
    private ConnectThread connectThread = null;
    private ConnectedThread connectedThread = null;
    private int bluetoothState = STATE_NONE;

    public BluetoothService(Handler handler) {
        this.bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        this.bluetoothState = STATE_NONE;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public synchronized void startConnection() {
        Log.d(TAG, "start");

        if (this.connectThread != null) {
            this.connectThread.cancel();
            this.connectThread = null;
        }

        if (this.connectedThread != null) {
            this.connectedThread.cancel();
            this.connectedThread = null;
        }

        this.setBluetoothState(STATE_LISTEN);
    }

    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (this.bluetoothState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (this.connectThread != null) {
                this.connectThread.cancel();
                this.connectThread = null;
            }
        }

        if (this.connectedThread != null) {
            this.connectedThread.cancel();
            this.connectedThread = null;
        }

        this.connectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        this.connectThread.start();

        this.setBluetoothState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (this.connectThread != null) {
            this.connectThread.cancel();
            this.connectThread = null;
        }

        if (this.connectedThread != null) {
            this.connectedThread.cancel();
            this.connectedThread = null;
        }

        this.connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        this.connectedThread.start();

        Message msg = this.handler.obtainMessage(Globals.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString(Globals.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);

        this.handler.sendMessage(msg);
        this.setBluetoothState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    public synchronized void stopConnection() {
        if (this.connectThread != null) {
            this.connectThread.cancel();
            this.connectThread = null;
        }

        if (this.connectedThread != null) {
            this.connectedThread.cancel();
            this.connectedThread = null;
        }

        this.setBluetoothState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    public void write(byte[] out) {
        ConnectedThread connectedThread = null;

        synchronized (this) {
            if (this.bluetoothState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                return;
            }

            connectedThread = this.connectedThread;
        }

        connectedThread.write(out);
    }

    private void connectionFailed() {
        Message msg = this.handler.obtainMessage(Globals.MESSAGE_TOAST);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Globals.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");

        msg.setData(bundle);

        this.handler.sendMessage(msg);

        BluetoothService.this.startConnection();
    }

    private void connectionLost() {
        Message msg = this.handler.obtainMessage(Globals.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString(Globals.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);

        this.handler.sendMessage(msg);

        BluetoothService.this.startConnection();
    }

    public synchronized int getBluetoothState() {
        return this.bluetoothState;
    }

    private synchronized void setBluetoothState(int bluetoothState) {
        this.bluetoothState = bluetoothState;
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;
        private BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = null;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
            this.bluetoothDevice = bluetoothDevice;

            BluetoothSocket tempBluetoothSocket = null;

            try {
                tempBluetoothSocket = this.bluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + "create() failed", e);
            }

            this.bluetoothSocket = tempBluetoothSocket;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");

            this.setName("ConnectThread");

            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                this.bluetoothSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);

                connectionFailed();

                try {
                    this.bluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                }

                return;
            }

            synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
                connectThread = null;
            }

            connected(this.bluetoothSocket, this.bluetoothDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                this.bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;
        private InputStream inputStream = null;
        private OutputStream outputStream = null;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");

            this.bluetoothSocket = bluetoothSocket;

            InputStream tempInputStream = null;
            OutputStream tempOutputStream = null;

            try {
                tempInputStream = this.bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
                tempOutputStream = this.bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            this.inputStream = tempInputStream;
            this.outputStream = tempOutputStream;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes = 0;

            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = this.inputStream.read(buffer);

                    handler.obtainMessage(Globals.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);

                    connectionLost();

                    BluetoothService.this.start();

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                this.outputStream.write(buffer);

                handler.obtainMessage(Globals.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                this.bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If no: How to exchange the UUID's to be able to connect the devices?

Comment: Yes, For pairing, it can't be done automatically how far I worked. You have to show a list of visible Bluetooth device around your mobile on the app and user need s to select one from them.

Comment: So the pairing makes sure that the exchange of the uuid's takes place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UUID defined in the google sample/example must be known by the server and the client :

- The server create a RFcomm ServerSocket that listen for incoming connection with this UUID
- The client create a RFcomm bluetoothsocket that will try to connect to the server socket

if the uuids matches the connection is established.

The pairing saves the informations about the remote device (name, adress, ... etc) so that when you want to connect again you don't have to search for the device to get them =)

Comment: Ok but than i dont understand how i could connect to different devices. My Nexus 7 Tablet is opening the connection (only! There will never be another device trying to open the connection) so is the nexus 7 the server or the client? Later i want to controll two different micro controllers and they both have a fix UUID and they are not equal. So how could i controll both micro controllers when they dont have the same UUID?

Comment: For your Nexus 7, the device that open the connection and wait for other device is the server. In fact you use a serverSocket. For connecting to several micro controllers the server must know the UUID list and create a ListenningThread for each one. Each thread create a serverSocket with a different uuid. When connecting your micro controllers will try to connect on every UUID until one match (because you don't know wich one will be taken first)

Comment: Thank you 1000 times. That topic was killing me the last days.